# Where should this android database code live?

Tags: android, database, conceptual

I'm working on an android application, and I'm having an issue figuring out where some code should live.

The application is based on some of the Commonsware stuff, along with the Notepad tutorial.  It has projects, and each project can be opened, have properties edited, or "ran".

Right now, there's a dbadapter class that has the basic CRUD operations for a "project".  It doesn't seem to make sense to put the open, edit, or run methods in there, because those methods involve starting activities, and I can't do that from inside the dbadapter.

I currently have the code inside the detail view for the project.  I want to be able to call those same methods from context menus in other activites than the detail view.

Where should the code live?  Should I have a Project class?  How would that interface with the dbadapter and cursors?  Should I make some sort of invisible Fragment--probably not, but I'm grasping at straws a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your database code from the activities.. Having CRUD operations in DB adapter is a good practice. You can also write a provider on top of that database which can use those CRUD operations at the top level to maintain the community between your activities and the database.